# when press back button activity does not finish

Tags: java, android

My app contains two activities and First activity load data from web using volley and after successful loading of data start second activity, the second activity contains dynamic tabs and view pager. My issues is when i press back button from second activity does not finish the activity but restart second activity again and it will finish when press ten times of back button that is my tabs count is 10, any one can help me to solve this issue..

**First Actvity, SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String HOME_URL = "http://sampleurl.com/beta/Mobile_controller";
public static ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getCategories();
}

private void getCategories() {
    categories = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HOME_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray categoryJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("category");
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
                    JSONObject cat = categoryJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    model.setCategoryID(cat.getString("category_id"));
                    model.setCategoryName(cat.getString("category_name"));
                    categories.add(model);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("error : " + error.getMessage()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

}

**Second Activity MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

MediaController mediaController;

private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_home);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    categoryList = SplashActivity.categories;

    NavigationView navDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_home);
    navDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_home);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_home);
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(categoryList.get(i).getCategoryName()));
    }
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_home_content);
    SwipingTabsAdapter swipingTabsAdapter = new SwipingTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), categoryList, tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipingTabsAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_option_home, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_option_search).getActionView();
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_option_account:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
```

}

**View pager Adapter**

```
public class SwipingTabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int tabs;
private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList;

public SwipingTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories, int tabCounts) {
    super(fm);
    this.categoryList = categories;
    this.tabs = tabCounts;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    /*switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new NewsCategoriesFragment();
        case 1:
            return new NewsCategoriesFragment();
        default:
            return new NewsCategoriesFragment();
    }*/
    return NewsCategoriesFragment.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(categoryList.get(position).getCategoryID()));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs;
}
```

}

**My fragment**

```
public class NewsCategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<SliderModel> sliderNews;
private SliderNewsAdapter sliderNewsAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_categories, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    int id = bundle.getInt("id");
    getNews(id);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp_slider_news);
    sliderNewsAdapter = new SliderNewsAdapter(getContext(), sliderNews);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sliderNewsAdapter);
    button.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    return view;
}


public static Fragment newInstance(int id) {
    NewsCategoriesFragment fragment = new NewsCategoriesFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("id", id);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

private void getNews(final int categoryId) {
    sliderNews = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, NEWS_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray sliderNewsJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("slider_news");
                for (int i = 0; i < sliderNewsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    SliderModel model = new SliderModel();
                    JSONObject data = sliderNewsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    model.setNewsThumbImg(data.getString("news_thump_image"));
                    sliderNews.add(model);
                }
                sliderNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "JSON Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf("error "+ error.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("id", String.valueOf(categoryId));
            return data;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(request);
}
```

}

Comment: are you calling the second activity on splash screen after a timeout?

Comment: calling after loading data from web not timeout

Comment: call `finish();` on your `SplashScreen` activity after calling your `SecondActivity`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you put your startActivity inside the for loop, put start activity after for loop in Splashactiivty getCategories,  it will work fine

Change this,

```
try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray categoryJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("category");
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
                    JSONObject cat = categoryJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    model.setCategoryID(cat.getString("category_id"));
                    model.setCategoryName(cat.getString("category_name"));
                    categories.add(model);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

to

```
try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray categoryJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("category");
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
                    JSONObject cat = categoryJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    model.setCategoryID(cat.getString("category_id"));
                    model.setCategoryName(cat.getString("category_name"));
                    categories.add(model);

                }
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in second activity override as
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       finish();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to Launch a intent to previous activity. Android has something called **Back Stack** which contains previous launched activities in a stack data structure.You could have just overridden onBackPressed() method to get it done.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        this.finish();
}
```

Also note launching intent as **NewTask** helps you to get away from existing backstack and has its own backstack.